# Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cucumber, android-gradle-plugin

```
  ./gradlew --parallel :app:assembleDebugTest
```

when i run above command in **android studio** terminal i got this error.

**Error**
Parallel execution is an incubating feature. 
 **Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location 'sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W' (Expected 'sdk/build-tools/20.0.0')**

Gradle file
           apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
    android {
            compileSdkVersion 22
            buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
            packagingOptions {
                    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            }
            defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "package"
                    minSdkVersion 15
                    targetSdkVersion 22
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                    testApplicationId "package.test"
                    testInstrumentationRunner "package.test.Instrumentation"
            }
            buildTypes {
                    release {
                            minifyEnabled false
                            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
            }
            sourceSets {
                    androidTest {
                            assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
                    }
            }
            adbOptions {
                    timeOutInMs 60000 // set timeout to 1 minute
            }
    }

    dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
            compile project(':sdk')
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.4') {
                    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            }
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.4') {
                    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            }
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1') {
                    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            }

            androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
            androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
            androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
            androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
                    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
                    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
                    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
                    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
            }

            androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.0@jar'
            androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.0'
    }
```

Reference : **Cucumber** Android Test  [link](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/android/android-studio/Cukeulator)

Comment: Restarting Android Studio + Clean worked for me

Answer (score 13):

I faced same error yesterday

uninstalling the build-tools:20 worked for me

answer on this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199518) was helpful

Answer (score 5):

rename the folder

"sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W"-> "sdk/build-tools/20.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

Why do you guys complicate if the warning is self-explanatory?

> Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location 'sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W' (Expected 'sdk/build-tools/20.0.0')

Just amend the location accordingly

```bash
sudo mv sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W sdk/build-tools/20.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**May be you have two build tools folder with the same version**. In this case you might have two build tools folder for 20.0.0 version. Delete any one of them will resolve the issue.

Otherwise, **your build tools got corrupted**. So, delete the folder or uninstall it using android studio or SDK manager then install it again.